# VBA - exporting data from cells based on selected row(s)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet. I would like to export data from specific cells based on the selected row or rows and import them into a new spreadsheet with a table.

I am not sure how to go about this in excel. I have tired a range but it copies everything. I would like it to be if i select row 5 it take data from B5, E5, F5

I plan to use a userform and macros with a command button to perform this function but i can do all this with no issues

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Look into the [Intersect Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835030.aspx), it would look something like this for you: `Set rCopy = Intersect(rSelected.EntireRow, Range("B:B,E:F"))`

Comment: I guess I am still confused. what does does is save the cell values for B E and F from the selected row correct. What if i want multiple rows selected and how do i go about pasting those into entire different spreadsheet in different rows.

Comment: You'll need to show your code, sample data, and expected results.